# Create geography polyline from points in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, geospatial

I have a table schema that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LongAndLats](
[Longitude] [decimal](9, 6) NULL,
[Latitude] [decimal](9, 6) NULL,
[SortOrder] [int] NULL
)
```

Sample data looks like this:

[image]

How can I convert these points into a geography polyline using TSQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:
(**note**: the ordering of the points is important for the line to be generated correctly.)

```
DECLARE @BuildString NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @BuildString = COALESCE(@BuildString + ',', '') + CAST([Longitude] AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ' ' + CAST([Latitude] AS NVARCHAR(50))
FROM dbo.LongAndLats
ORDER BY SortOrder             

SET @BuildString = 'LINESTRING(' + @BuildString + ')';   
DECLARE @LineFromPoints geography = geography::STLineFromText(@BuildString, 4326);
SELECT @LineFromPoints
```

Comment: I suggest to avoid `SELECT @var = @var + '' ... ORDER BY ...` construct. [Group by value and create geography polyline from points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48241483/group-by-value-and-create-geography-polyline-from-points-latitude-and-longitude/48241575#48241575)

Comment: @lad2025 Good point. That link says `applying a function or expression to the columns in the SELECT list *should* produce deterministic behavior` (as in the answer), they also go on to say `The correct behavior for an aggregate concatenation query is undefined`. The alternative constructs in your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48241575/2293226), based on a similar question are more reliable. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: String aggregation using COALESCE is apparently not safe: https://marc.durdin.net/2015/07/concatenating-strings-in-sql-server-or-undefined-behaviour-by-design/