# Create geography polyline(s) from points for many features in same table in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, geospatial, sqlgeography, sqlgeometry

A similar question has been asked here:

[Create geography polyline from points in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259914/create-geography-polyline-from-points-in-t-sql)

I have a table schema that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LongAndLats](
[Longitude] [float] NULL,
[Latitude] [float] NULL,
[SortOrder] [bigint] NULL,
[SensorID] [bigint] NULL,
)
```

Sample data looks like this:

[image]

How can I convert these points into a geography polyline **for each SensorID** using TSQL (so that I would have a SensorID/Polyline record for each SensorID)?

Comment: One way would be to open a cursor on the distinct `SensorID`s and inside the cursor run the code in the duplicate answer, but adding a `WHERE` clause to filter on the `SensorID`

Comment: Thanks...I had a little success playing around with that thought.  Being new to the cursor concept, how might one go about joining each result?  Say I ultimately want a view with x rows as opposed to x result sets?